# Responsive footer in Angular with bootstrap that is always at the bottom of the page. Not Sticky

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, angular

I'm trying to make a responsive footer for the website I'm working on.
The footer needs to always be at the end/bottom of the page even if the content of the page only takes up half of the page.

I've tried using the code in this example but I can't get it to work.

The footer must not be sticky it must either show after all the content of the page after scrolling to the bottom of the page or if there is no content then it must sit at the bottom of the page.

I have a footer and a header component and they are displayed in my app component.

This example I found on code pen didn't work for me but it is the exact behavior I want. - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OxJooY

```
<div class="demo">
  <h1>CSS “Always on the bottom” Footer</h1>
   <p>I often find myself designing a website where the footer must rest at the bottom of the page, even if the content above it is too short to push it to the bottom of the viewport naturally.</p>
   <p>I often find myself designing a website where the footer must rest at the bottom of the page, even if the content above it is too short to push it to the bottom of the viewport naturally.</p>
   <p>I often find myself designing a website where the footer must rest at the bottom of the page, even if the content above it is too short to push it to the bottom of the viewport naturally.</p>
   <p>I often find myself designing a website where the footer must rest at the bottom of the page, even if the content above it is too short to push it to the bottom of the viewport naturally.</p>

  <p>I often find myself designing a website where the footer must rest at the bottom of the page, even if the content above it is too short to push it to the bottom of the viewport naturally.</p>

  <p>However, if the content is taller than the user’s viewport, then the footer should disappear from view as it would normally, resting at the bottom of the page (not fixed to the viewport).</p>

  <p>If you know the height of the footer, then you should set it explicitly, and set the bottom padding of the footer’s parent element to be the same value (or larger if you want some spacing).</p>

  <p>This is to prevent the footer from overlapping the content above it, since it is being removed from the document flow with <code>position: absolute;</code>.</p>
</div>

<div class="footer">This footer will always be positioned at the bottom of the page, but <strong>not fixed</strong>.</div>
```

//Css file of my app component

```
body {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 6rem;
  min-height: 100%;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}



.demo {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 64px;
  max-width: 640px;
  width: 94%;
}

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #efefef;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide the code block....

Comment: Hi Minal, A colleague at work did manage to help me. I posted the answer below as I couldn't find anything else on the Internet that worked.

Answer (score 13):

//Add this to the app component HTML file and to the app component css file

```
<div class="page-wrapper">
    <div class="sticky-header">
        <app-header></app-header>   /* your header component */
    </div>
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div class="content">
            Your content goes here or another page's component.
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <app-footer></app-footer>  /* your footer component */
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


        .page-wrapper {
            height: 100vh;
            width: 100vw;
            overflow: hidden;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
        }

        .sticky-header {
            flex-grow: 0;
            min-height: 60px; /* whatever you want it to be */
        }

        .content-wrapper {
            flex-grow: 1;
            overflow-y: auto;
            overflow-x: hidden;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
        }

        .content {
            flex-grow: 1;
        }

        .footer {
            min-height: 60px; /* whatever you want it to be */
            flex-grow: 0;
        }
```

Comment: 4 years later, and this STILL works with Angular 4 and Bootstrap 4 lol... with no upvotes. Just... criminal.

Comment: AND this solves the Bootstrap 4 sticky header issue with vertical spacing. I just about gave up on it, tried your code and was please to see I had a fully functioning Sticky header with no need to manipulate padding or marginality for the top portion of the body. Kudos!